# Which soil works for Dracaena sanderiana (lucky bamboo)?

Tags: indoors, soil, potting-soil, dracaena

I got this Dracaena sanderiana (lucky bamboo) recently, and would like to replant it in a different pot and change the soil:

[image: picture]

I've done some googling and got wildly different and often times opposing answers on which type of soil to use. I have some leftover peat moss, perlite, cactus soil and regular flower soil and am unsure if any of those are a good option. I found some answers where people said that a peat moss and perlite combination is a good option but no note about the ratio how much of which to use. Also, because of all of the different answers online, I'm unsure if that is a good option at all.

In short, my question is: Is a peat moss and perlite combination a good type of soil for an indoor Dracaena sanderiana or is there something better? And if it is, what ratio of the two to use?

P.S.

I've also found some tips on growing the plant without soil, however this is not an option I would like to take.

Answer (score 1):

Peat moss and perlite will work just fine.  Try for 60-70% peat moss & 40-30% perlite.  I always go for 40%.  I just like to have really well draining soil.  But, either of those ratios will work.   In a few months, check the ph of the run off/discharge water.

You could just use the regular flower potting mix.  That will have probably have peat, perlite & some dolomite lime to balance the ph.

Answer (score 0):

I doubt the soil makes much difference , sanderiana loves water. Unscrupulous pet shops sell it for aquariums; it can live under water for as long as a year. I expect in nature it is a bog plant.